How can a loop through the selections of a query in postgresql?
this is my code in postgresql, and it works perfectly fine:
select 
    case 
        when cfd.value like '%TryUSI%' then 'TryUSI'
        when cfd.value like '%Workshop%' then 'Workshop'
        when cfd.value like '%KOOP%' then 'KOOP'
        when cfd.value like '%dual%' then 'dual'
        when cfd.value like '%NEU%' then 'Neu'
        else 'kein Tag'
    end as Tag, count(bo.id)
from mdl_booking_options bo
join mdl_customfield_data cfd on cfd.instanceid = bo.id  and cfd.fieldid = 5
where bo.bookingid = 17
group by Tag;

But I would like my code to be more generic. Something like:
DEFINE $variable = 'SELECT botags from table2'
select 
    case 
        when cfd.value like '%$variable%' then variable
        else 'kein Tag'
    end as Tag, count(bo.id)
from mdl_booking_options bo
join mdl_customfield_data cfd on cfd.instanceid = bo.id  and cfd.fieldid = 5
where bo.bookingid = 17
group by Tag;

Anyone any idea how I could get the pseudo code working?

There's no loops in SQL, but you can achieve this with a subquery:
select 
    coalesce((
        select botags
        from table2
        where cfd.value like '%' || botags || '%'
        -- order by ???
        limit 1
    ), 'kein Tag') as Tag, count(bo.id)
from mdl_booking_options bo
join mdl_customfield_data cfd on cfd.instanceid = bo.id  and cfd.fieldid = 5
where bo.bookingid = 17
group by Tag;


try this
select coalesce(bt.botags, 'kein Tag') as Tag, count(bo.id)
from mdl_booking_options bo
join mdl_customfield_data cfd on cfd.instanceid = bo.id and cfd.fieldid = 5
left join botags bt on cfd.value ~ bt.botags
where bo.bookingid = 17
group by Tag;

